# R Plotly Animated dumbell chart: Subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am attempting to make an animated dumbbell chart in `plotly` with `R`.

Following the example [here](https://plot.ly/r/dumbbell-plots/) and using the info [here](https://plot.ly/r/animations/), I came up with the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  category=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  year=c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001),
  val_a=c(1,2,2,1,2,5,6,8),
  val_b=c(3,5,4,7,1,9,2,12)
)

plot_ly(data = df, frame = ~year) %>%
  add_markers(x = ~val_a, y = ~category, name = "Val_A", color = I("red")) %>%
  add_markers(x = ~val_b, y = ~category, name = "Val_B", color = I("blue")) %>%
  add_segments(x = ~val_a, xend = ~val_b, y = ~category, yend = ~category, showlegend=F) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Val A v Val B",
    xaxis = list(title = "Value"), 
    yaxis = list(title = ""),
    margin = list(l = 65)
)
```

Unfortunately this throws the following error:

```
Error in which(idx)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
18.
registerFrames(p, frameMapping = frameMapping)
17.
plotly_build.plotly(instance)
16.
instance$preRenderHook(instance)
15.
createPayload(x)
14.
toJSON(createPayload(x))
13.
widget_data(x, id)
12.
htmltools::tagList(container(htmltools::tagList(x$prepend, widget_html(name = class(x)[1], package = attr(x, "package"), id = id, style = style, class = paste(class(x)[1], "html-widget"), width = sizeInfo$width, height = sizeInfo$height), x$append)), widget_data(x, id), if (!is.null(sizeInfo$runtime)) { ...
11.
toHTML(x, standalone = standalone)
10.
as.tags.htmlwidget(x, standalone = TRUE)
9.
htmltools::as.tags(x, standalone = TRUE)
8.
isTag(ui)
7.
rewriteTags(x, function(uiObj) { if (isTag(uiObj) || isTagList(uiObj) || is.character(uiObj)) return(uiObj) else return(tagify(as.tags(uiObj))) ...
6.
tagify(x)
5.
renderTags(html)
4.
save_html(html, file = index_html, background = background, libdir = "lib")
3.
html_print(htmltools::as.tags(x, standalone = TRUE), viewer = if (view) viewerFunc)
2.
print.htmlwidget(x)
1.
(function (x, ...) UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

However, if you run the plot code with **either** the markers **or** the segments, it works fine. Why then can I not seem to combine them?

Comment: It’s how it’s done in the example plotly docs I linked. I’m fairly certain it’s also not the problem, since animating the lines by themselves works fine. The plot also works fine without animation, if you just want to draw a static dumbbell chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the trace names your code works! (name = "Val_A")

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Madhu's answer is to add a name for your add_segments with `name = "Val_C"`. This way, each add_X has its own name and Plotly is not confused. Not intuitive but I had the same problem and this worked. You can then of course suppress the name and legend entry with
`showlegend = FALSE` and `hoverinfo = 'none'`.